# Rabbitmq file size

Tags: linux, rabbitmq

My queue file size is growing to gigantic sizes in RabbitmQ. But the queue has zero items in it. Why and how can I keep this from happening? It seems after it happens the rabbitmq takes for ever to restart.

Rabbit MQ version 2.1 
RHEL 5.5

[15:04:11 root@....:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia]# ls
rabbit  rabbit@zenoss02
[15:04:12 root@....:/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia]# du -sh
31G

any ideas?

Comment: Have you had a look at your memory use?  RabbitMQ doesn't behave so well in low memory situations.

Comment: Turned out it was the App hammering the queue with requests in a short period time. The workers couldn't keep up.